# Calculating the SD for the z-test

Tags: standard-deviation, z-test

The following picture, taken from some lecture notes, shows a very strange formula for calculating the SD, that I have never come accross. Can somebody explain how this formula yields the SD, even though I was originally taught another formula (square root of variance)?

[image]

Comment: This formula *is* the square root of a variance.  The variance is based on a Binomial distribution.

Answer (score 0):

That $\sigma_{p}$ looks like a standard error for the proportion.

- The variance for a single Bernoulli case is $\pi (1-\pi)$
- so the variance for the sum (i.e. binomial) is $n\pi (1-\pi)$
- and variance for the sample proportion $\frac1n\pi (1-\pi)$.

Then take the square root